# Can I populate one field based on the value (or lack of value) in another field?

Tags: formula-field

The source field has a picklist of values on it. But critically, the values in this field may not all match valid picklist values. For example:

Field_A__c
picklist: Hamburger
picklist: Hotdog

I want a proposed Field_B__c field to have a value based on the values in Field_A__c. So if Field_A__c's value is 'Hamburger', then Field_B__c's value should be 'Beef'. That sounds pretty simple, right?

My issue is what happens when Field_A__c has a value of 'Pizza'. But 'Pizza' is not one of those picklist values I noted above. How do I update Field_B__c's value in this scenario?

**More Info**

- The current number of unique Field_A values is 10. This is
  specifically the amount of picklist items available to choose.
- The current number of unique Field_B values is 5.
- Some values of Field_A are not in the picklist values because the Restrict picklist... option is unchecked on the field & new "non-picklist" values could still be added.

I think this chart should help visualize what I want?

| Field_A | In Picklist | Field_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pizza | TRUE | Dinner |
| Hamburger | TRUE | Dinner |
| Eggs | TRUE | Breakfast |
| Salad | TRUE | Dinner |
| Tuna Sandwich | TRUE | Lunch |
| Ice Cream | TRUE | Dessert |
| Toast | TRUE | Breakfast |
| Steak | TRUE | Dinner |
| Potato Chips | TRUE | Lunch |
| Tacos | TRUE | Dinner |
| Cake | FALSE | Dessert |
| Bacon | FALSE | Breakfast |
| Water | FALSE | Other |

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). More information is needed in order to attempt to help you. Please edit your question to include the following: **(1)** What is current number of unique `Field_A` values? **(2)** Unique `Field_B` values? **(3)** Are some values of `Field_A` not in the picklist values because A) it is "old" data (e.g., from before the field became a picklist field, "retired" picklist values, bulk data load)? Or B) because the *Restrict picklist...* option is unchecked on the field & new "non-picklist" values could still be added? (Or create a "C)" if something else.)

Comment: Thanks - all that is helpful. It would be simpler if you wanted the 10 `Field_A` picklist values to match up to the 5 `Field_B` values, and then everything else NOT in the `Field_A` picklist get lumped into **one** value in `Field_B`. You have added layers of complexity to want the `Field_A` non-picklist values to then be parsed and matched with specific `Field_B` values....

Comment: *BTW, "Bacon" should map to "Breakfast", "Lunch", Dinner", "Supper", "Dessert", "Snack", "Other"... Just sayin'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be if you wanted all non-picklist values of `Field_A` to cause a value of "Other" in `Field_B`.

But since all of your non-picklist `Field_A` values do not map to the same `Field_B` value; and since in the future new `Field_A` values could be added that need to map to specific `Field_B` values; it seems that there is going to have be list maintenance done somewhere by someone.

Looking closely at your samples, it turns out that the values of `Field_B` do not really depend on whether the value of `Field_A` is in the picklist - the `Field_B` values just depend on the actual values of `Field_A`.  That makes using a formula field more plausible.

It is a little bulky, but if you want admins to be able to maintain this whenever new `Field_A` values are added, then you could make `Field_B` a **text formula field** like this:

```
CASE(
  Field_A__c,
  "", "",
  "Hamburger", "Dinner",
  "Pizza", "Dinner",
  "Salad", "Dinner",
  "Steak", "Dinner",
  "Tacos", "Dinner",
  "Eggs", "Breakfast",
  "Toast", "Breakfast",
  "Bacon", "Breakfast",
  "Tuna Sandwich", "Lunch",
  "Potato Chips", "Lunch",
  "Ice Cream", "Dessert",
  "Cake", "Dessert",
  "Other"
)
```

- The `"", "",` line makes `Field_B` blank when `Field_A` is blank. (This could probably be left out if `Field_A` is *required*.)
- The `"Other"` as the last item makes any non-blank value in `Field_A` which is not explicitly listed here show an "Other" in `Field_B`. This might 'buy you time' when a new `Field_A` value gets added until the formula could be updated. *(Or you could explicitly list which values you want to be "Other", and then let the last 'default' value be something like "Not yet determined" which could be a signal that the `Field_A` value needs to be added to this list.)*

---

This could be done in Apex, but that would need developer maintenance whenever a new `Field_A` value is added - unless the code was made dynamic to read a mapping of `Field_A` > `Field_B` values from an admin-maintained source. But to me - as much as I love Apex - that seems a bit over the top for this.

Similar thought regarding a Flow - it seems like overkill in this case.